# Neo4j.Driver.V1.ServiceUnavailableException: 'Failed after retried for 5 times

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a simple dotnet and neo4j project but i can't connect to the localhost.

This how my connection look like

```
   using (Program greeter = new Program("bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "test"))
                {
                    greeter.PrintGreeting("hello, world");
                }
```

This is the method that i am trying to call

```
    public void PrintGreeting(string message)
    {
        using (var session = _driver.Session())
        {
            var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
            {
                var result = tx.Run("CREATE (a:Greeting) " +
                                    "SET a.message = $message " +
                                    "RETURN a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)",
                    new { message });
                return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
            });
            Console.WriteLine(greeting);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give the full error/stack you've got ?and also the full code of `Program` ?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2KgDOX  here is the full code

Comment: Neo4j.Driver.V1.ServiceUnavailableException: 'Failed after retried for 5 times in 30000 ms. Make sure that your database is online and retry again.' 

This the error